# Unable to Create table and List tables to remote HBase using JAVA

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

**trying to connect HBase Remotely only, same code works in locally:**

THIS IS PROGRAM:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    HBaseConfiguration hconfig = new HBaseConfiguration(new Configuration());
    hconfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.*.***");
    hconfig.set("hbase.master", "192.168.*.***:60000");
    hconfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
    HTableDescriptor htable = new HTableDescriptor("User"); 
    htable.addFamily( new HColumnDescriptor("Id"));
    htable.addFamily( new HColumnDescriptor("Name"));
    System.out.println( "Connecting..." );
    HBaseAdmin hbase_admin = new HBaseAdmin( hconfig );
    System.out.println( "Creating Table..." );
    hbase_admin.createTable( htable );
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

After this line is throwing an error:

```
HBaseAdmin hbase_admin = new HBaseAdmin( hconfig );
```

**Error:**

```
15/10/06 11:22:05 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server quickstart.cloudera/192.168.*.***:2181, sessionid = 0x1503670c5dc00b5, negotiated timeout = 60000
Creating Table...

15/10/06 11:23:02 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=10, retries=35, started=57048 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=

15/10/06 11:23:23 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=11, retries=35, started=78252 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=
```

These are my Jar files:

```
commons-configuration-1.6.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
hadoop-core-1.0.0.jar
hadoop-common-1.0.0.jar
hbase-server-1.0.0-cdh5.4.2.jar
hbase-client-1.0.0-cdh5.4.2.jar
hbase-0.92.0.jar log4j-1.2.16.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
zookeeper-3.4.2.jar
```

and includes all the jar files which are located in hadoop path `/usr/lib/hbase/lib/`

And I have copy the hbase-site.xml file to my project and also add the remote ip address into etc/host file too.

I'm facing problems, while creating a new table in to remote hbase and trying to fetch table list from hbase using java client!

But with the same jar files, I can able to do other more operations like Get, Put and other few, except Creating table and Listing Table!

Kindly do favor me.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following dependency in your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
     <artifactId>hbase-client<artifactId>
     <version>1.1.0.1</version>
<dependency>
```

Instead of setting hbase configuration details individually add **hbase-site.xml** & **core-site.xml** as resources to `Configuration` object and use it

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.addResource(new Path("/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml"));
config.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
```

Once you have Configuration object create the `Connection` and get `Admin` object

```
Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();
```

And then you can use the following code snippet to create HBase table along with the column families.

```
if (!admin.isTableAvailable(TableName.valueOf("user"))) {
    HTableDescriptor hbaseTable = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf("user"));
    hbaseTable.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("id"));
    hbaseTable.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("name"));
    admin.createTable(hbaseTable);
}
```

For more details [refer this](https://khodeprasad.github.io/blog/create-table-in-hbase-using-java/)

for working code sample you can [refer this](https://github.com/khodeprasad/java-hbase/blob/master/src/main/java/com//khodeprasad/hbase/CreateTable.java)

Comment: I seen the shared link. I appreciate the interest and its more useful.              Can you please text me the proper jar to connect remote hbase?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the dependency that you need to use. what distribution you are using in your cluster and what is the HBase version?

Comment: are you still facing the problem or that resolved the issue?

Comment: thanks for asking nicely, but still i can't able to achieve. this line is not executing "Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();"

Answer (score 0):

Since you were able to perform put and get, it should not be a jar issue. Can you try adding this property `zookeeper.znode.parent` with value "/hbase-unsecure" in hbase config. Its the the root znode that will contain all the znodes created/used by HBase. In zookeeper client jar, this value is "/hbase". Compare it with your config xml files. You can look [here](http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/hbase-session-not-established-infamous-zookeeper-znode-parent-error/)

Comment: Yes, I added those property in my coding. conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.*.***");
      conf.set("hbase.master", "192.168.*.***:60000");
      conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
      conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent","/hbase-unsecure");                   But still this line is not executing        hbase_admin.createTable( htable );                                                                  This is the problem i'm facing from the beginning.

Comment: Vivek, did you finally solved the problem? I'm facing the same issue with Hbase version 1.2.1. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.  I fixed it by opening the following ports in the HBase nodes:

1. 60000
2. 60010
3. 60020
4. 9090

In Centos 7:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=60000/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=60010/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=60020/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9090/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

More information [here](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/07/guide-to-using-apache-hbase-ports/)